# Reg:chrome extensions-calling chrome.webstore.install in javascript dragend function

Tags: google-chrome-extension, inline, failed-installation, chrome-web-store

chrome.webstore.install is working for onclick function to add an app to chrome extensions,but when i tried with the other events it is throwing an exception Uncaught Chrome Web Store installations can only be initated by a user gesture.Please confirm and update asap it will work only for onclick.If it is also work for other events please update because i need in dragend function to add an app to chrome extensions.When i gone through search in many places this is used in onclick function.

Answer (score 0):

yes, works only for onClick. dragEnd is not considered a user gesture.